# What is the relationship between the velocity of a wave source and the amplitude of a shock wave?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, acoustics, interference, shock-waves

I'm having trouble understanding the kind of interference leading to shock wave formation and how it relates to the velocity of the wave source.I came across this image: [image]

It illustrates the formation of a shock cone from spherical wavefronts at supersonic wave source velocity. From what i see, even if the wavefronts were much more closer than the image depicts, overlap would still not occur at every point on the shock wavefront. Does this imply that amplitude of a shockwave is not uniform? How would wave source velocity affect this(Is there a mathematical relationship)?

I'm not concerned with the velocity of propagation of the shock wavefront or with the changes in temperature,pressure and density upstream and downstream of the shock wavefront. I'm only concerned with the amplitude of the shock wave and the mechanism of interference as it relates to the velocity of the wave source.

Comment: Do you know what the (almost) vertical stripes represent? They travel to the left with a much smaller velocity as the emerging wavefronts.

Comment: @descheleschilder i think they are part of some previously generated wavefronts and they travel to the left with a velocity equal to the difference between the velocity of wave propagation and the velocity of  the wave source.

Comment: If you know the amplitude distribution over individual rings it looks like you can just sum left-moving rings which increase in size and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In the picture, the slow-moving wavefronts as well as the fast-moving wavefronts have their source in the engine in the plane (lets assume the rate at wich wavefronts are emitted represent the frequency of the plane's motor). In the picture, the plane is moving at a higher speed than that of sound in the right direction. The wavefronts of the motor move both to the left in this case. If you watch a circle (wavefronts, which are continuously emitted from the motor of the plane) emerging from the plane, the left side is moving at a speed higher than the speed of sound from the plane (relative to the plane).
The fast velocity with which this sound removes itself from the plane is $v_{fsp}=v_s + v_p$.
The slower moving sound (the right side of the circles) of this wavefront (also moving to the left) is $v_{ssp}=v_p-v_s$.

It's obvious that the fast (to the left moving) wavefronts can't interfere with the slow-moving wavefronts because these fast wavefronts are ahead of them.

**Except** where the fast and slow wavefronts (from different moments of their emission) meat at the edges of the cone. There the slow part and the fast part of the wavefronts enhance each other.
This enhancement (a supersonic bang) moves over the ground so you can hear the bang. The higher the frequency of the motor, the more energy is contained in it, and the bang increases in intensity.
After the bang, you can't hear the plane anymore because the sound waves emerging from the plane can't reach you. From the frame of the plane, the waves are traveling faster than the speed of sound but according to an observer on the ground, these waves can't reach him/her.

So only the bang is heard, whose intensity is higher if the frequency of the motor is higher or the plane is going faster.

If the plane is moving at the speed of sound the cone becomes a straight line. In this case, a bang is also heard, and after passage, there is silence as the speed of sound is relative to the plane, not to the ground.

If the plane is flying below the speed of sound you can imagine no bang is heard, but the plane is heard flying by with the usual Doppler effects.

Comment: how do all the waves add up at all points, when overlap occurs at only some points? Also what does the waveform look like(i assume it is not sinusoidal)?

Comment: That's the point. They overlap at all points at the edges of the cone (constructive or destructive) to make up a periodic wavefront at the edges, which can only be heard for a very small time when arriving at your ears, because of the thinness of the this (I think it's sinusoidal, or cosinusoidal; this makes, of course, no difference). But that it's periodic is for sure. Only we can't hear that because the shock lasts that short. After the shock, you'll hear the sound which the object produces, which can be a (Doppler affected) sine wave, or whatever.

Comment: overlap will occur at all points on the cone edge only if there are absolutely no spaces between the wavefronts(circles). So rather than periodic wavefronts, we would have a continuum of wavefronts. Is that possible? Also is there anyway to calculate the amplitude?

Comment: You're right. I think there is indeed no interference, but the strength of the wavefront at the edges is constant (well, in fact, grows smaller with distance, because the wavefronts grow bigger with distance. If I stand 1(km) from a JSF traveling at a supersonic speed, the bang (the  "spike" on the edges of the cone) I hear a louder band than if I stand 10(km) away from that damned JSF.

Comment: I'll leave the calculation for others to make, but I think it's not such a difficult calculation, although...

Comment: I'm not saying there is no interference. I'm saying there is interference at only some points on the shock wavefront(cone edge), rather than at every point on the shock wavefront. This should lead to a non-uniform amplitude.

Comment: How can there be interference if there is only **one** source producing the sound waves? I can't see how these waves interfere with themselves.

Comment: Constructive interference would occur at every point of overlap(intersections between circles), since they are in phase. There are such points in the image and they all lie along the shock wavefront(cone edge), which appears to be a straight line, but a closer look will show that it's actually not a straight but approximately so, because they are also points along the apparent line where there is no intersection(interference).

Comment: There can't be interference because each new circle lies totally within the preceding one up to the continuum level (when the circles aren't shown one after another, like in the animation. I think you see interference between the actual waves that are sent out and the lines moving slowly to the left (which aren't actually there).

Comment: The lines moving to the left with a lower velocity are the right ends of previously generated wavefronts with a  velocity equal to the difference between the velocity of wave propagation and the velocity of the wave source. The left ends of newer generated wavefronts catch up to and intersect with them leading to interference.

Comment: It only looks like there is interference, which is very obvious if you look at the animation. There is also clearly an interference visible in the middle of the cone (on a horizontal line coming out of the source). But do you think the waves really interfere in the middle?

Comment: I would say yes, the interference starts at the middle and spreads out, but i would like to know what constitutes an interference in your opinion. What i know to be constructive interference is simply an overlap between wavefronts in phase. Would you object to this?

Comment: I agree. But these wavefronts have to come from two different sources. Suppose the source isn't moving so the waves spread out symmetrical around the source. Do these waves interfere?